# Get Latitude and Longitude from google location autocomplete using vue.js in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using google autocomplete and getting location data but i want to get latitude and longitude with city, country and state name too.

```
<vue-google-autocomplete
    id="map"
    classname="form-control"
    placeholder="Start typing"
    v-on:placechanged="getAddressData"
    v-model="form.address"
>
</vue-google-autocomplete>


 getAddressData: function (addressData, placeResultData, id) {
            this.address = addressData;
            console.log(placeResultData.geometry.location.lat);
            console.log(placeResultData.geometry.location.lng);
        }
```

Comment: What is the current output of your placeData that you log to the console. Is it completely incorrect or does it return some useful data, just not the long + lat?

Comment: @Jordan: It return arrays of information linke administrative area level 1 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do, lat and long are placed on addressData, not on placeResultData where you have info about the place related to that address.

```js
getAddressData: function (addressData, placeResultData, id) {
    this.address = addressData;

    console.log(addressData.longitude);
    console.log(addressData.latitude;

    this.form.address = addressData.route + ', ' + addressData.postal_code + ', ' + addressData.administrative_area_level_2 + ', ' + addressData.country;
  }
```

Also, I do not think the use of v-model makes much sense here, instead you should store the address directly on the getAddressData function.

```js
<vue-google-autocomplete
    id="map"
    classname="form-control"
    placeholder="Start typing"
    v-on:placechanged="getAddressData"
>
</vue-google-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Thanks It is working, i'm also getting state but it is working in short form, can you please let me know how i can i get long names for states.